# Qt StyleSheet Text Alignment

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to change the appearance of a QGroupbox. The problem is about the border of it. After changing the style sheet, the text of the groupbox is not aligned with the border anymore. How can this be solved?

In the first picture, the border is well aligned with the text:

[image]

The style sheet related to this QGroupBox is like this:

```
QGroupBox{
background-color: rgb(0,80,120);
color: white;
font: 14pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
font: bold;
text-align:center;
}
```

In the second picture, the border is aligned with the bottom of the text:

[image]

The style sheet related to QGroupBox above is like this:

```
QGroupBox{
background-color: rgb(0,80,120);
color: white;
font: 14pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
font: bold;
text-align:center;
border-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 9px;
padding: 2px;
}
```

As you can see, when I add border related parameters, text alignment somehow changes. I want the first style but with the text aligned properly with the border. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Its actually not the text but the border thats being corrupted. It moves from top indent to upper edge.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. But you should adjust margin / padding. And sub controls. I propose you to read [Qt stylesheet reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qgroupbox).

Comment: It is wrong, just add a border: 2px solid; and you will see the border being drawn above the title instead of beside the title, without the title being moved.

Comment: QSS in Qt - it's a king of magic. I wasted a lot of time on adjusting all borders, margins and paddings. So I only can propose to do experiments.

Comment: @SebastianLange adding a property "border: 2px solid" does not help. The border moves up above the title.

Comment: I commented the post, that the 2px solid corrupts the border, that was no solution, sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: This problem is solved by adding an item to StyleSheet:  
QGroupBox::title {
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
  subcontrol-position: top left;
 padding:0;
 } 
Thanks for help.